# Is there a substitute for matplotlib.pyplot.colors?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying the function on this [doc](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.colors.html)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.colors()
```

got this error

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-e2c1adbcc48e> in <module>
      1 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
----> 2 plt.colors()

AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'colors'
```

the doc says

> The colors function was deprecated in version 2.1.

without providing a substitute.

is there a substitute for matplotlib.pyplot.colors?

Comment: `plt.colors()` does nothing. You can use the `matplotlib.colors` module for color processing: https://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html

Comment: what exactly you want to do? please check this [matplotlib.colors](https://matplotlib.org/2.1.1/api/colors_api.html)
may be it help.

Comment: I want a list of available colors and its Alias, like 'b', blue. and ImportanceOfBeingErnest has gave a perfect answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be more precise here: No, there is no substitude for `matplotlib.pyplot.colors` because its only purpose was to allow users to get help via `help(plt.colors)`. It was considered more harmful to confuse users by the presence of this function, which doesn't do anything, than it to be useful to let them get help on colors via pyplot. If you want to get help on colors now, you may still type

```
help(matplotlib.colors)
```

though that is a bit more lengthy.